# How to implement the function which is interacts with elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here, I need to set the selected property only for those elements ***option*** in which the corresponding ***li*** has selected class. Value is determined by the attribute *data-input-value* at the ***li*** and the value attribute in ***option***.

```
<div class="wrapper">
        <select name="name">
          <option value="val1">name1</option>
          <option value="val2">name2</option>
        </select>
        <ul data-input-name="name">
          <li data-input-value="val1" class="disabled">name1</li>
          <li data-input-value="val2" class="enabled selected">name2</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

Comment: when will this selected class will be applied to a `li`

Comment: You may also consider adding `onClick` action to the options of the select and pass to the invoked function the name of the `li` you want the function to act on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('select[name="name"] option').each(function() {   
  if ($('li[data-input-value="' + $(this).val() + '"]').hasClass('selected')) {
    $(this).prop('selected', true);   
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <select name="name">
    <option value="val1">name1</option>
    <option value="val2">name2</option>
  </select>
  <ul data-input-name="name">
    <li data-input-value="val1" class="disabled">name1</li>
    <li data-input-value="val2" class="enabled selected">name2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! This is what I was looking for